# How to view all properties of an AD User object?

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I recently started playing around with power shell and just finished reading the learn PowerShell in a month of lunches book.

I'm playing around with the `Get-AdUser` cmdlet and I'm confused about all the AD users properties. for example:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {name -like "ryan*"} | Format-Table *
```

It's my understanding that `| Format-Table *` or `| get-member` should return all properties of an object. However I came across this command:

```
Get-ADUser -filter {name -like "ryan*"}  –Properties "DisplayName", "msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed"
```

That adds a `DisplayName` and `msDS-UserPasswordExpiryTimeComputed` properties to the objects.

My question is why weren't these properties listed under `get-member`? Is there a way I can view all the properties of `get-aduser`?

Comment: It shows you all properties _requested_. When you ask for more it shows you more.

Comment: okay.. how to i request that it show all properties of an object? I though |gm should show me everything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [W]hy weren't these properties listed under get-member?

`Get-Member` will show you all the members, properties etc. of the object requested. It is doing exactly what you asked of it<sup>1</sup>.

`Get-Aduser` has a default property set it gets from AD e.g. DisplayName, samaccountname and etc. If you want more then you need to ask for more. From [TechNet for Get-Aduser](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ee617241.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

> **Properties**
>
> Specifies the properties of the output object to retrieve from the server. **Use this parameter to retrieve properties that are not included in the default set**.
>
> Specify properties for this parameter as a comma-separated list of names. **To display all of the attributes that are set on the object, specify * (asterisk)**.

So if you use `-Properties *` you will get all of that AD objects properties. Understand that `-Properties *`, while simple to use, is a performance hog as it queries for non-indexed attributes. If you can, reduce your selection set to just the ones you actually need.

---

<sup>1. There are some hidden properties of PowerShell objects that `-Force` exposes but that is not what you are asking about.</sup>

Comment: Glad to hear it. Consider marking the question as accepted using the green check mark if you feel your question is resolved.